# N1QL Query using index and USE KEYS

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I need to perform a N1QL query where some of the records can be selected by an indexed attribute and others can be identified by their IDs.  I tried to use

```
SELECT name FROM b WHERE collection in $cList OR meta().id IN $idList
```

But this returns an error saying there is no index available that matches my query.  I can use UNION with 2 separate queries:

```
SELECT name FROM b WHERE collection in $cList
UNION
SELECT name FROM b USE KEYS $idList
```

Is that the best way to do this?  Or is there some way to combine results from an index and USE KEYS in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Union query is best option because USE KEYS can get directly from KV and other part of query can use index.